# c++ console application, How do I print a character outside of the console

Tags: c++

So I have a console application and I want the console application to print/paste characters into any other programm. Is it possible for a console application to write something outside the console window?

Comment: One common way to accomplish this is to run your C++ application within the other application as a system call and then read in the output from the it. For example, in Python you can use `subprocess` and in Perl use `system` or backticks.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you can not. If you develop the other application you could find a way through IPC or shared memory.